# Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

Tags: angular, ionic2, mean

I got run time error:

> Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
>       Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
>           at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:2793
>           at XMLHttpRequest.open (eval at s (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:29793), :3:31)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Reviews {


  data: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.data = null;
  }

  getReviews(){

    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      this.http.get('http://localhost:app/api/reviews')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });

  }

  createReview(review){

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('http://localhost:app/api/reviews', JSON.stringify(review), {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res.json());
      });

  }

  deleteReview(id){

    this.http.delete('http://localhost:app/api/reviews/' + id).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res.json());
    });    

  }

}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> ```
> http://localhost:app/api/reviews
> ```

This is an invalid URL (just like the error message says).

If you have a `:` after the hostname, it must be followed by a port NUMBER (and then the path). `app` is not a number, it is three letters.

Answer (score -1):

It might becouse of incurrect IP/  in Env file.

Ex- apiLogin: 'http://192.168.1.71:5000',  --Currect
apiLogin: 'http://192.168..71:5000',    --Incurrect

So check Env file IP Or Ngrok

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

The problem is with your URL. Read the error message properly it's saying invalid URL

Here you are using `localhost:app` in your URL `'http://localhost:app/api/reviews'` which is incorrect. You have to use some kind of open port number instead of random text. For example `3000`, `4000`, `5000`, `8080`, `8000`, etc.

So your URL will be like this `'http://localhost:3000/api/reviews'`